# Solving Dirac equation with intial state $\psi_0$

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-equation

Consider intial state $\psi(0,\vec{r})=\psi_0(\vec{r})$ of Dirac spinor. I want to find $\psi(t,\vec{r})$. I want to decompose $\psi_0$ in plane wave solutions using some kind of Fourier transform. Then to integrate those values over momentum. So, basically my question is how do I decompose $\psi_0$ in plane waves $u(\vec{p})e^{i\vec{p}\vec{x}}$ (no time component here)

Comment: Can you clarify the sense in which this differs from the ordinary, non-relativistic QM case? Is it just that you have a "column" of functions rather than a single one?

Comment: In fact, yes, but the problem is that components of $u$ also depend on momentum